# How to save and get data from iOS SQLite database?

Tags: swift, sqlite, decodable

I would like to te "label" and "slug" String from the database. They are printed well in init(from decoder: Decoder), but I probably do something wrong with saving them, because anywhere else they're gone.

This is my Decodable Class

```swift
import Foundation
import SQLite

final class AdditionalField : Decodable {

    var label : String?
    var slug : String?
    var data: Any?
    var type: QuestionType?
    var pollQuestion: PollQuestion?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case label = "label"
        case slug = "slug"
    }

    required init(from row: Row) {
        label = row[Columns.label]
        slug  = row[Columns.slug]

        if let dataString = data as? String, let data = dataString.data(using: .utf8) {
            self.data = type?.create(from: data)
        }
    }

    required  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        label = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .label)
        print(label!)
        print("label")

        slug = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .slug)
        print(slug!)
        print("slug")
    }
}


extension AdditionalField: SQLTable {

    static var tableName = "AdditionalField"

    enum Columns {
        static let label = Expression<String>("label")
        static let slug = Expression<String>("slug")
    }


    static func createTable(db: Connection) throws {
        try db.run(table.create(ifNotExists: true) { table in
            table.column(Columns.label)
            table.column(Columns.slug)
        })
    }

    static func insert(elements: [AdditionalField]) throws {
        try Database.shared.insert(elements: elements)
    }

    func insert(db: Connection) throws {
        try db.run(AdditionalField.table.insert(or: .replace, [
            Columns.label <- label ?? "",
            Columns.slug  <- slug ?? ""
        ]))
    }

}
```

I've tried to used them like that. Maybe here is the problem ?

```swift
//   let field = additionalFields?.filter{$0.label == anyTextField.placeholder}.first

       // anyTextField.placeholder = field?.label
```

Comment: you have not included any code where you are trying to save to or fetch from the database.  And how is json decoding relevant to your sql issue?

Answer (score 0):

I created a library called [SundeedQLite](https://github.com/noursandid/SundeedQLite)

Feel free to try it!